# Popup window using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, popup, modal-dialog

i am trying to open a page in popup using ModalDialog. 
Issue: The popup window get closed before it gets loaded.

Code:

```
function ShowPopup(id, rowIndex) {  
    var options = {
        title: "Add User Account",
        width: 750,
        height: 800,
        url: "/sites/Main/sitepages/Home.aspx"
    };

    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}

 this.btnAccOk.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:ShowPopup(0,0);");
```

Comment: hi Geetha you can use AJAX ModalPopup refer : http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
function ShowPopup(id, rowIndex) {  
    var options = {
        title: "Add User Account",
        width: 750,
        height: 800,
        url: "/sites/Main/sitepages/Home.aspx"
    };

    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
return false;
}

 this.btnAccOk.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return ShowPopup(0,0);");
```

Try above code.i have made few changes

Comment: A small suggestion for future reference: it's always better to detail the changes, rather than copy/paste/amend a block of code. Otherwise you have to compare the two piece of code line by line to see the differences. It not too bad with something this size, but I see people doing it with blocks of 20/30/40+ lines, and it's impossible to tell